# How can I play an m3u8 video live instead of playing old segments?

Tags: live-streaming, http-live-streaming, m3u8, m3u

I have an m3u8 video that if I just start with the first segment it is behind the live version of the stream. But in some players it plays live just fine, so my thinking is that there must be some magical way of knowing how to play the stream live but I don't see anything on the manifest telling me this.

So what should I be looking for?

Thank you.

Comment: Read the pantos spec. It’s all in there.

Comment: Thanks for that info. I've read the whole thing and still didn't find anything I could use to do what I want to do. `EXT-X-START` seems to be the closest but my m3u8 files don't have that. I also don't seem to get a `EXT-X-PROGRAM-DATE-TIME`. The only thing that was semi close was `If the EXT-X-ENDLIST tag is not
   present and the client intends to play the media normally, the client
   SHOULD NOT choose a segment which starts less than three target
   durations from the end of the Playlist file.` but that doesn't tell me how to play it live, just what I shouldn't do.

Comment: @casolorz The last segment in the playlist is the more recent. If you start within less than three target durations you risk stalling the playback. You're *always* behind the live event by at least the duration of the last segment. What're you trying to do exactly?

Comment: @aergistal I have a stream that if I play with the first segment it is about 3 hours behind. The user wants to play it close to live. So if I'm understanding right, I would start on the 3rd segment from last and that would be live? Thanks.

Comment: @casolorz no, not 3 segments. 3 target durations. Target duration is the max duration. Segments can be shorter.

Comment: Ohh, good point, thank you for that correction. I have done some preliminary testing and this seems to work. If you want to write it as an answer I will gladly mark it correct.

Comment: @aergistal one more question. My users have two types of videos, infinite live m3u8 and and finite m3u8 videos. If I go to the last 3 target durations on the finite ones then it will only play a few seconds and then end which won't be good. I noticed other video players are able to distinguish between those two types. I'm guessing because of the `#EXT-X-ENDLIST` tag at the end of the m3u8. Is that the correct way to determine this? Thanks.

Comment: @casolorz There are three playlist types: **Live** - sliding window / fixed number of segments, **VOD** - all segments + ENDLIST, **Event** - records all segments of a live event and once it's over adds the ENDLIST transforming it in a VOD playlist. For Live/on-going Event you should play the most recent, while for VOD/finished Event you should start with the first.

Comment: @aergistal thank you, that is very helpful. How can I detect the type prior to playing the video?

Comment: @casolorz `EXT-X-PLAYLIST-TYPE` if present. Check the standard.

Comment: Yeah I saw that on the spec but I've never actually seen it on any of the videos I'm looking at. The only differentiator I have found so far is `#EXT-X-ENDLIST`